# How to number the number of times , the condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to loop this code so that every time when new high/low  is formed it should display the number as high 1 , high 2 / low 1 , low 2 like that.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Day High/Low', overlay=true)
t = time('1440', session.extended)  // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
plotshape(is_first, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=shape.arrowdown)

day_high = float(na)
day_low = float(na)

if is_first and barstate.isnew
    day_high := high
    day_low := low
    day_low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]
    day_low

if high > day_high
    day_high := high
    day_high

if low < day_low
    day_low := low
    day_low

plot(day_high, color=color.new(color.lime, 0))
plot(day_low, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Day High/Low', overlay=true)
t = time('1440', session.extended)  // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
plotshape(is_first, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=shape.arrowdown)

day_high = float(na)
day_low = float(na)

var int Hi_Count = 0
var int Lo_Count = 0

if is_first and barstate.isnew
    Hi_Count := 0
    Lo_Count := 0
    day_high := high
    day_low := low
    day_low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]
    day_low

if high > day_high
    Hi_Count := Hi_Count + 1
    day_high := high
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=low, text="High " + str.tostring(Hi_Count), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.new(color.lime, 50), textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

if low < day_low
    Lo_Count := Lo_Count + 1
    day_low := low
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text="Low " + str.tostring(Lo_Count), style=label.style_label_down, color=color.new(color.red, 50), textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

plot(day_high, color=color.new(color.lime, 0))
plot(day_low, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
```

This will start counting from the first change. It acts like a counter. If there is any confusion on any part, please let me know.